# PMServerCreatePrinterList(kPMServerLocal, &printerList) returning OSStatus code 1282

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Below is my code that is working with Command-Line tool but when I am creating an Cocoa App and I am using below code, not getting all printer queues from Mac OS X.

```
CFArrayRef printerList;   

if (noErr == PMServerCreatePrinterList(kPMServerLocal, &printerList) && (nil != printerList))
    {
        CFIndex count = CFArrayGetCount(printerList);
        NSLog(@"Count = %ld",count);
        for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
            PMPrinter myPrinter = (PMPrinter)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(printerList, index);
            NSString *name = (__bridge NSString *)(PMPrinterGetName(myPrinter));
            NSLog(@"%@",name);
        }
    }
```

Please help if anyone have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sandboxing issue. If your application didn't run in the sandbox, it'd work, otherwise you need the entitlement to allow it.

> (Domain: org.cups.PrintingPrefs, User: kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: No, Container: (null)): accessing preferences outside an application's container requires user-preference-read or file-read-data sandbox access, detaching from cfprefsd

In your target's Capabilities view in Xcode, turn on the "Printing" capability under App Sandbox -> Hardware.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I enabled Printing checkbox in Sandbox and now its working.

Comment: @Vasim No problem. Mark this as answered.